# python 2.7 sqlite3 cursor returns only one result

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm fiddling around with Python and SQLite. I have a table structured like so:

```
PID | CID | a | b
=================
1   | 1   | ...
1   | 2   | ...
2   | 1   | ...
2   | 2   | ...
```

where PID is the ID of one object, and CID the id of another. Basically, a table that keeps track of the relationships between these two objects with properties (a, b, etc...) that may override those of the objects.

When I execute the following statement in python (c is a sqlite3 cursor):

`results = c.execute("SELECT cid FROM test WHERE pid=?", (the_related_id,)).fetchmany()`

I only get one result in the list, however, when I run the same (?) query in a sqlite browser, I get many results as expected:
`SELECT cid FROM test WHERE pid=1`

Whats the deal?

Comment: `fetchmany` returns *n* many rows at a time and can be called more than once. Use `fetchall` instead.

Comment: @JonClements Please make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of rows to fetch per call is specified by the size parameter. If it is not given, the cursor’s arraysize determines the number of rows to be fetched.

```
    results = c.execute("SELECT cid FROM test WHERE pid=?", (the_related_id,)).fetchmany(N)
```

will return N rows. 
If you want to retrieve all the rows, use fetchall() function instead:

```
    results = c.execute("SELECT cid FROM test WHERE pid=?", (the_related_id,)).fetchall()
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks! I completely forgot about `fetchall()`!